# In Graphhopper, how can I retrieve the set of edges contained in a route?

Tags: java, routes, graphhopper

I am currently using GraphHopper within an application that detects whether a customer's route goes past a specific point of interest (PoI). One PoI has one or more roads through which a customer can pass it (predefined for each PoI).

The fastest way to do this, I think, is to find each customer route, and see whether the edges within a route include any edges that pass a PoI. The following code finds all of the edges closest to the points stored within a GHResponse object (called 'route' in the code below).

```
QueryResult qr;
HashMap<String, EdgeIteratorState> routeEdges= new HashMap<String, EdgeIteratorState>();
for(GHPoint p:route.getPoints()){
    qr = index.findClosest(p.getLat(), p.getLon(), EdgeFilter.ALL_EDGES );
    routeEdges.put(qr.getClosestEdge().toString(), qr.getClosestEdge());
}
```

This uses end-points of each road and searches for the closest edge, which I might return any of the edges at that node. I'd much prefer a list of edgeID's within the route, so I could compare them to the edges for each PoI instead.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: What does 'edge' mean? A line contained within the route?

Comment: Currently this internal is not exposed to any public method in the GraphHopper class. So you would need to use the lower level API. Or you could overload GraphHopper.getPaths and store Paths somewhere and then call path.calcEdges

Comment: Ubica - an edge in GraphHopper (as I understand) is a bidirectional edge that connects two junction/tower nodes (I could be wrong).

Comment: Karussell - thanks for the tip. Your advice seems to work well except when looking at a route's start and end points. Where a start or end point of a route and the PoI fall between two tower nodes, the edge seems to be described differently and it is not detected. Do you have any advice on accounting for this?

Comment: GraphHopper will create two virtual edges but still with the same 'original' edge which can be used to match them. You can get the 'original' edge via the QueryResult.getClosestEdge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advice from Karussell, I created my own custom GraphHopper object that implements a specific method to return the edges used in a route.

```
public class GraphHopperWithPaths extends GraphHopper {

public List<Integer> routePaths(double startY, double startX, double endY, double endX){

    //Examine a route and return edgeIDs that GraphHopper uses
    LocationIndex index = this.getLocationIndex();
    GHRequest request = new GHRequest(startY, startX, endY, endX);
    GHResponse response = new GHResponse();
    List<Path> paths = getPaths(request, response);
    List<Integer> edges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Path p:paths){
        for(EdgeIteratorState e:p.calcEdges()){
            edges.add(e.getEdge());
        }
    }
    if (response.hasErrors()) return null;

    //Get edges for start and end point as well
    QueryResult qr = index.findClosest(startY, startX, EdgeFilter.ALL_EDGES );
    edges.add(qr.getClosestEdge().getEdge());
    qr = index.findClosest(endY, endX, EdgeFilter.ALL_EDGES );
    edges.add(qr.getClosestEdge().getEdge());

    return edges;
}

}
```

This method doesn't return the route itself, which means that it should be modified if you want both the routes and the edges. Running both the `route` and `routePaths` method of this custom GraphHopper object would be inefficient.